# In "The Blues Brothers", what is the significance of the food order?

Tags: analysis, the-blues-brothers

In *The Blues Brothers*, Jake orders four whole fried chickens and Elwood orders dry white toast.

My best guess on why Jake orders the chicken is a reference to the song “Back Door Man” (“...I eat more chicken than any man ever seen...”). This seems to jive with Jake’s personality.

I have no idea what the dry white toast might refer to. Any guesses?

Answer (score 7):

There doesn't seem to be any special significance to the specific foods mentioned. The impression I got from the scene is that the "four whole fried chickens and a Coke/dry white toast" are what Jake and Elwood regularly order, allowing Matt "Guitar" Murphy to realize they're in the diner before he steps out of the kitchen and sees them. In other words, their unusual eating habits act as a humorous calling card by which their bandmates/friends can recognize them.

Other than "announcing" their arrival, the order might also be considered a reflection of Jake and Elwood's personalities: the four fried chickens and Coke match Jake's reckless, disruptive nature, and the dry white toast matches Elwood's generally rather mild and low-key nature.

> SOUL FOOD CAFE
>
> ARETHA
>   Help you boys?
>
> ELWOOD
>   You got any white bread?
>
> ARETHA
>   Yes.
>
> ELWOOD
>   I'll have some toasted white bread please.
>
> ARETHA
>   You want butter or jam on that toast, honey?
>
> ELWOOD
>   No ma'am, dry.
>
> JAKE
>   You got any fried chicken?
>
> ARETHA
>   Best damn chicken in the state.
>
> JAKE
>   Bring me four fried chickens and a Coke.
>
> ARETHA
>   You want chicken wings or chicken legs?
>
> JAKE
>   Four fried chickens and a Coke.
>
> ELWOOD
>   And some dry white toast please.
>
> ARETHA
>   You all want anything to drink with that?
>
> ELWOOD
>   No ma'am.
>
> JAKE
>   A Coke.
>
> ARETHA
>   Be up in a minute.
>
> [She goes back to the kitchen.]
>
> ARETHA
>   We got two honkies out there dressed like Hasidic diamond merchants.
>
> MATT
>   Say what?
>
> ARETHA
>   They look like they're from the CIA or something.
>
> MATT
>   What they want to eat?
>
> ARETHA
>   The tall one wants white bread, toast, dry, with nothing on it.
>
> MATT
>   Elwood!
>
> ARETHA
>   And the other one wants four whole fried chickens and a Coke.
>
> MATT
>   And Jake! Shit, the Blues Brothers!
>
> [Matt goes out into the cafe.]

Referred to copy of script [here](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/bluesbrothers_script.pdf) for the relevant dialogue.